# SUMIFS where the "sum_range" column is unknown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a pile of data on Sheet1
I have a `SUMIFS` formula on Sheet2
The columns I am summing are named `NETPERD1`, `NETPERD2`, `NETPERD3`.....`NETPERD12`

I want to write the `SUMIFS` so that I can easily change which column I am summing.
On Sheet2, in cell `$C$4`, I will enter `NETPERD1` or `NETPERD2` etc.  and I want my `SUMIF` to determine which column it should sum.
I think I should be able to do this with `IndexMatch`  but I can't get it to work.

Here is my `SUMIFS` that works.
I want to replace `NETPERD1` with `$C$4`

```
=SUMIFS(Sheet1!NETPERD1,Sheet1!ACCTGRPCOD,Perplas!$A15,Sheet1!AUDTORG,Perplas!C$1,Sheet1!FSCSDSG,Perplas!C$2,Sheet1!FSCSYR,Perplas!C$3)
```

[image: Data on Sheet1]

Comment: Something like `=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z,,Match(Perplas!C$4,Sheet1!A$1:Z$1,0)),...` Change the `Z` to whatever your rightmost column is. Though what row do your named ranges end at? Are they the entire column?

Comment: @BigBen For me that's a total valid answer to be posted

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - agreed, added for posterity :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your named ranges span the entire column, then for the INDEX/MATCH try:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$Z,,Match(Perplas!C$4,Sheet1!A$1:Z$1,0)),...
```

changing the `Z` to your rightmost column.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the indirect function. You can supply indirect with a character string that Excel then reads as part of a cell/range reference.

Working off the code you shared + the fact that you said that you'll put in the name of the range in cell C4:

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&$C$4),Sheet1!ACCTGRPCOD,Perplas!$A15,Sheet1!AUDTORG,Perplas!C$1,Sheet1!FSCSDSG,Perplas!C$2,Sheet1!FSCSYR,Perplas!C$3)
```

I think that should work? I'm a little confused about how you're able to reference the row name without a named range, so that might cause a wrinkle in this.

Comment: I hope it works! LMK if it doesn't because that means I must've mistyped something.